# creating file in shell then replacing text inside

Tags: bash, shell, replace

I have a script where i declare variables then create a file and then replace a variable within that file, this is my example script

```
#!/bin/bash

DMNAME = mydomain.com

cat <<EOF > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

server_name DMNAME;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DMNAME/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DMNAME/privkey.pem;
EOF

sed -i 's/DMNAME/mydomain.com/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

#
```

Would this be the correct way of replacing DMNAME with mydomain.com ?

Comment: Is the creation of the file just for this question? If not why not just put the domain directly in the here-doc? If it is, then yes, that is one way of replacing the text in the file, except your assignment which can't contain spaces.

Comment: You can't have spaces in variable assignments.

Comment: Also the assignment is pointless, as you never reference the variable.

Comment: Yes created the file just for this question, forgot about the spaces thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

DMNAME="mydomain.com"

cat <<EOF > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server_name $DMNAME;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DMNAME/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DMNAME/privkey.pem;
EOF
```

Comment: So the variable assignment must not have spaces and be in quotes? Then referenced with "$" Thanks

Comment: @LVM - no quotes around the `=`, and it's always a good idea to use quotes around your content ... mostly when you're *using* a domain, though the here-doc may be an exception to that rule. Consider that it might be safer to redirect `cat`'s output to some other file, then move that file to the target location if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

@Bor is right that he fills `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` with the correct values when creating it.
When you want to use default.conf more than once, you shouldn't let `sed` change the file with the `-i` option, but redirect the results to the file you want.

```
# Answer: do not use this here: DMNAME = mydomain.com

cat <<EOF > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server_name DMNAME;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DMNAME/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DMNAME/privkey.pem;
EOF

# And now DMNAME="mydomain.com" (without spaces, quotes are optional here).
# or for different domains

confpath="/etc/nginx/conf.d"
for domain in mydomain.com yourdomain.com hisdomain.com; do
   sed "s/DMNAME/${domain}/g" "${confpath}"/default.conf > "${confpath}"/${domain%.*}.conf
done
```